# Dependent method registration | Element i.d. availability

Tags: javascript

How can one register event handlers to elements that are currently loaded into the DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just test them for existence first:

```
var signup, signin, bookmark;
if(signup = document.getElementById('signup'))
    signup.onclick = interface_signup;
...
```

etc.